# Using return JS

Tags: javascript

What for using return in such situations?

```
<div class="s" onclick="return goNav();">click</div>
```

What is difference?

```
<div class="s" onclick="goNav();">click</div>
```

Both variants work

Or:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var linkWithAlert = document.getElementById("alertLink");
    linkWithAlert.onclick = function() {
        return confirm('Вы уверены?');
    };
};
```

Comment: If the `goNav` function returns `false` then the default click action will be canceled, which doesn't mean much on a `div` element but it could on an anchor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `return` of `onclick` can be `false`. In that case, the default `onclick` action wouldn't be triggered:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/" onclick="return confirm('Really?')">Go to SO</a>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/" onclick="confirm('Really?')">Go to SO</a>
```

In the first case, if you click on No, you're not redirected, in the second case, you are. That means that without using `return` you can trigger your function without breaking the browser`s default.